# Adding custom content to wordpress posts, with variables such as $title not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used this code to add custom content to all my wordpress posts.

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {
        $content .= '<strong>'. $title . '</strong> is a <strong>wallpaper</strong> posted in the ' . $cat_name  . ' category.';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

The problem is that the post title and category are not showing so all I am getting is basically "is a wallpaper posted in the category".

How could I modify the code so that the post title and category are pulled to be added to the description?

Here is the code which works for some posts created using a specific plugin, but I would like it globalized to all posts on the site

```
        //Create Post
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();   

    $imagePoster->dirName = time(); 

    $wp_upload_dir =  wp_upload_dir();

    if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
    {           
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $originalFilename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $zipMessage = $imagePoster->unzip($filename , $originalFilename);           

        $images = $imagePoster->iterateDir($wp_upload_dir['basedir'].'/bulkimages-'.$imagePoster->dirName.'/'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $filename = $_POST['manualfile'];
        $images = $imagePoster->iterateDir($wp_upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.$filename.'/');
        $zipMessage = '';   
    }       

    $postCount = 0;

    $titleExploded = explode(",", $titleList);
    $linkExploded = explode(",", $linkList);

    $initialInterval = $statusSplit[1];
    $interval = $statusSplit[1];    

    foreach($images as $image)
    {   
        if(get_option('create-posts-from-images-useimagename') == true)
        {   
            if(get_option('create-posts-from-images-delimiter') != '')
            {           
                $path_parts = pathinfo($image->getFilename());
                $title = str_replace(get_option('create-posts-from-images-delimiter')," ",$path_parts['filename'] );                    
            }           
            else
            {
                $path_parts = pathinfo($image->getFilename());
                $title = $path_parts['filename'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $title = $imagePoster->loopTitles($titleExploded, $postCount );             
        }                   

        $link = $imagePoster->loopTitles($linkExploded, $postCount );

        $cat_name = get_cat_name( $category );

        $content = '<strong>'. $title . '</strong> is a <strong>Wallpaper</strong> posted in the ' . $cat_name  . ' category.<br /><br />';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked in wordpress but try var dumping out the following in the shortcode.

```
$GLOBALS['post']
```

You should be able to get what you want doing something like...

```
$GLOBALS['post']->post_name
```

to test this in your code above do the following.

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    global $post;
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {
        $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
        $cats = array();

        foreach($post_categories as $c){
            $cat = get_category( $c );
            $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
        }

        $content .= '<strong>'. $post->post_title . '</strong> is a <strong>wallpaper</strong> posted in the ';

        foreach($cats as $c){
           $content .= $c['name'];
        }

        $content .= 'categories';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but i'm unsure how i can go about doing that. How would I modify the code I have above to var dump what you mentioned in the shortcode?

Comment: I added in an example for you. that will get you what you want for the title. I'm modifying it right now to get categories since they are always a huge pain in wordpress.

Comment: Ok that should work. It will need for formatting to look nice and a little extra logic for if it's in multiple categories but I believe it should run. Let me know if not so I can fix it.

Comment: hmm, that is strange. I added the code as you mentioned to the bottom of my functions.php file but the posts show absolutely nothing.

Comment: odd i may have an error as I don't have anything to test this code on. try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', '1'); for the first 2 lines of the function and seeing if any errors are popping up. Also i updated the code slightly.

Comment: Ok I removed the . in the $content .= part and now it shows the description. However, for some reason, the title is being derived from the oringinal file name for the image that the post was created from and not the new images. For example, all dividers such as - are replaced with a space by a plugin on my site when adding images which are created as posts. I have added a segment of my functions.php file to my original posts which works fine when bulk uploading using a specific plugin, but does nothing for all the other posts which were added manually.

Comment: I was planning on removing it and using something more global to work across all posts on the site. Please take a look at my original post to see the code which work on specific posts that were created using the plugin.

Comment: What you are asking for at this point is essentially to write a plugin for you :P . to do what you want you will have to modify the code to not be based on only files and hook into the function using add_action( 'save_post', 'your-custom-save-post' );

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry. You have been extremely helpful so far and I'm sure I can find a use for your code. I didn't mean for you to wi=rite a plugin for me, I was just baffled a bit by how it works perfectly for the posts which were created using the plugin whereas the titles and categories don;t show when trying to add the code to all posts using the code we have modified. I thought by pasting some of the code (I'm not sure if that was all of it by the way) we can use the same $title and $category parameters set by the plugin to work across all posts.

Comment: The actual title of the post however, doesn't have the - seperators, so i'm not sure why the code we wrote is reverting to the file name to get the title

Comment: No problem at all. It wouldn't be bad to use that code for everything on the site if it wasn't so file specific so it would need a bit of work. I fixed the issue with it including the - it's actually post_title and not post_name that we wanted.

Comment: Here is the docs I was using for accessing post data if of help http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! Thank you very much for your help. I had a feeling there was something we were missing ;) Thanks again.

Comment: One more question (sorry :p) it seems that while now the code is working perfectly, I have duplicates for the old posts which have had the custom content added to their actual post contents using the old code and the new descriptions which are now universal. In the content-single.php file the line which calls both is  <?php the_content(); ?> Is it possible to modify this line and our code so that only the new code will be called and not the actual post content which was created with the old code.

Comment: This is possible but I would have to see what the name of the other function that is hooking into the_content it should look like add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content'); with add_after_post_content the only part that is different. Once we know that we can unregistered the hook before it gets called. Make sure to make the question as accepted as I believe it does answer your original question.